# Installing Linux-3.19 API Headers in LFS giving error

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-kernel, lfs

I am on chapter 6 of LFS and it is giving such error.
[image]

Please help me figure out what i am doing wrong.P.S i have entered chroot.

Comment: Which version of LFS is that? Linux 3.19?

Comment: LFS 7.7 and linux 3.19

Comment: Is it still updated? I mean the patches? Is there any reason you stick to that version?